# Out-File unnecessary characters

Tags: powershell

I have the script below which pings a list of machines, outputs the result to CSV and gets the lastlogontimestamp of the machine.

It works fine, except the lastlogontimestamp comes out like this:

```
CCC-APP01,172.22.100.15,@{lastLogonDate=07/25/2018 13:24:54}
```

How can I get rid of the extra characters: **@{lastlogondate=...}**?

```
$OutputCSV = "C:\TEMP\OUPingResults.csv"
$SearchLocation = "OU=AA,OU=Servers,DC=LocA,DC=XYZ,DC=com"

$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchLocation |
             Select Name |
             Sort-Object Name
$Computers = $Computers.Name
$Headers = "ComputerName,IP Address,LastLogonTimeStamp"
$Headers | Out-File -FilePath $OutputCSV -Encoding UTF8
foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
     Write-host "Pinging $Computer"
     $Test = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable Err
     if ($test -ne $null) {
          $IP = $Test.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
          $LastLogonTimeStamp = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Prop CN,lastLogonTimestamp |
                                Select @{n="lastLogonDate";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}
          $Output = "$Computer,$IP,$LastLogonTimeStamp"
          $Output | Out-File -FilePath $OutputCSV -Encoding UTF8 -Append
      } else {
          $Output = "$Computer,$Err"
          $Output | Out-File -FilePath $OutputCSV -Encoding UTF8 -Append
      }
}
```

Comment: Where did you copy the script from? :D

Comment: Can't remember, though IIRC it was cobbled together from various bits stolen from various places ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `... |Select-Object @{N='SomeName';E={"SomeValue"}}` will produce *an object* that has a property named `SomeName` with the value `"SomeValue"`.

What you see in the output is a string representation of this object.

If you want only the value, change the `$LastLogonTimeStamp` assignment to:

```
$LastLogonTimeStamp = [datetime]::FromFiletime((Get-ADComputer $Computer -Prop lastLogonTimestamp).lastLogonTimestamp)
```